# The assembled Python application does not launch

Tags: python, macos, build, pyinstaller

I built the application via Pyinstaller, added all the necessary folders to build the application, gave access to use third-party programs not from the App Store, added the required bin folder to PATH, disabled Gatekeeper, but nothing helped. It can only be launched through “Show package contents” - “Contents” - “MacOs” and there is a console application through which my application is launched. Why won't the .app launch?
This is how I assembled the application through the terminal:
python3 -m PyInstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --icon "/Users/s.p/Downloads/CustomTkinter_logo_single.ico" --add-data "/Users/s.p/Documents/programming/bg_gradient.jpg:." --add-data "/Users/s.p/Documents/logo_int.png:." --add-data "/Users/s.p/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/customtkinter:customtkinter/" "/Users/s.p/Documents/programming/My App 1.py"

Added all the necessary folders to build the application, gave access to use third-party programs not from the App Store, added the required bin folder to PATH, disabled Gatekeeper, but nothing helped.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Never the less, the most likely expanation is that you missed a dependency. Maybe a hidden import from one of the modules you use. https://www.pyinstaller.org/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.